# Django with mod_wsgi & apache incorrect redirect (no errors)

Tags: django, apache, url

I am having this strange problem with my django project. I am now using Django with apache & mod_wsgi, trying to make it work in production mode, however the url redirect does't seems to work. I am only able to access the site-index page but not any sub-urls. i.e. if I go to site-url.com/quzapp/ it shows the index page, which is exactly the same as if I go to site-url.com/

When I run it on the dev server, everything works just fine. I am always directed to the desired page. The wired thing is there is no error logged even though I've set the log down to debug level in the apache configuration.

When I check the access_log it shows like:

```
 "GET /quzapp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1935    (the quzapp page)

"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1935     (the site index)
```

The log seems OK but I can not see any page other than the site_index.html... What could be wrong?

Here is the brief structure of the site:
the project is called mysite with the main setting files sit in a sub directory also call mysite. quzapp is a django application.

```
mysite/
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
    mysite/ 
        settings.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        wsgi.py
    quzapp/
        __init__.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        admin.py
        forms.py
        models.py
        templates/
             quzapp/
                  base.html
                  …...
    template/
        siteindex.html
        …..
    static/…
    media/….
```

The main part of mysite/mysite/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^quzapp/',include('quzapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The main part of the mysite/quzapp/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.initial_form, name='index'),
    url(r'^allimage/$', views.allimage, name='allimage'),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^readytostart/$','questionnaires.views.register_success'),
    url(r'^audio/$', views.audio, name='audio'),
    url(r'^text/$', views.text, name='text'),
    url(r'^end/$', views.endpage, name='endpage'),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I printed out some text to see if all the urls.py files are accessed and the answer is yes. The print command leaves text messages in error_log, which shows mysite/mysite/urls.py is accessed first then mysite/quzapp/urls.py is accessed.

In the mysite/mysite/views.py  it returns render_to_response('siteindex.html'). I suppose this is how I got to access the siteindex page. The other pages are rendered in mysite/quzapp/views.py. Again I printed out some text message and in the error log, it shows the mysite/quzapp/views.py file is accessed after accessing the mysite/mysite/views.py.

I can't think of what's gone wrong and no error is logged, in the access log the status code is always 200 (ok). Does anyone have a clue about the problem?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: set you index url end with "$" : url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your main urls.py: you are not terminating the empty regex, so it matches everything. Make sure you use a final $:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Note that your print statements were unlikely to be helpful, because both urls and views files are loaded on startup. You would need to put print statements inside the view function, but you already know what view is being called.

Also note you shouldn't be including the admin urls both in the main urls.py and in the quzapp ones.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you so much for your kind help! This really solved my problem! Also, thank you so much for the suggestions. I will get the redundant admin urls removed:)